# Flutter CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod OneSignalXCFramework

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

on running `pod install` there is appearing following error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "OneSignalXCFramework":
  In Podfile:
    onesignal_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/onesignal_flutter/ios`) was resolved to 3.2.7, which depends on
      OneSignalXCFramework (= 3.9.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `OneSignalXCFramework (= 3.9.1)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try running the following command

```
cd ios/
pod repo update
rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods
pod install
```

Comment: the best solution so far for the existing problem

Comment: Totally worked!